# How to replace backslash and white space from string

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I replace "/" and " " from the given string "one size x/l" and generate output like "one-size-x-l" using preg_replace.

Comment: So the result you want from input string `one size x/l` is `onesizexl` ?

Comment: @Daniel:I wish to get the out put like "one-size-x-l"

Answer (score 2):

Using Regular expression you can replace all the special characters by "-" as below:

```
$str= "one size x/l";
$str= preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $str);
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function, which will make fnie urls as required

```
function seoUrlAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
            if( !empty($replace) ) { $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str); }

            $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
            $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
            $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
            $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

            return $clean;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $a="one size x/l";
```

echo preg_replace('*(/|\s)*','-', $a);

got my output as one-size-x-l